# PHP - Curitiba WS semrpe retorna 403

Tags: php, web-service

Estou tentando enviar uma NFS-e (XML, lote RPS) através do webservice de Curitiba, mas a conexão com o curl sempre retorna o erro 403 (sem permissão). Já vinculei o certificado no sistema da prefeitura (ISS). Segue as configurações abaixo:

**configurações do curl**

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, "{$path}_cert.pem");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, "{$path}_priKEY.pem");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD, '******'); // senha do certificado

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

**Headers**

```
    $headers = [
        'POST /Iss.NfseWebService/nfsews.asmx HTTP/1.1',
        'Host: isscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br',
        'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($xml),
        'SOAPAction: http://www.e-governeapps2.com.br/RecepcionarLoteRps'
    ];
```

XML Enviado (com dados de teste)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">   
  <soap:Body>
    <RecepcionarLoteRps xmlns="http://www.e-governeapps2.com.br/">
        <EnviarLoteRpsEnvio>
            <LoteRps>
                <NumeroLote>1</NumeroLote>
                <Cnpj>00000000000000</Cnpj>
                <InscricaoMunicipal/>
                <QuantidadeRps>1</QuantidadeRps>
                <ListaRps>
                    <Rps>
                        <InfRps>
                            <IdentificacaoRps>
                                <Numero>1</Numero>
                                <Serie>A</Serie>
                                <Tipo>1</Tipo>
                            </IdentificacaoRps>
                            <DataEmissao>2018-08-30 04:11:00T00:00:00</DataEmissao>
                            <NaturezaOperacao>1</NaturezaOperacao>
                            <RegimeEspecialTributacao>2</RegimeEspecialTributacao>
                            <OptanteSimplesNacional>1</OptanteSimplesNacional>
                            <IncentivadorCultural>2</IncentivadorCultural>
                            <Status>1</Status>
                            <Servico>
                                <Valores>
                                    <ValorServicos>1.00</ValorServicos>
                                    <ValorDeducoes>0</ValorDeducoes>
                                    <ValorPis>0</ValorPis>
                                    <ValorCofins>0</ValorCofins>
                                    <ValorInss>0</ValorInss>
                                    <ValorIr>0</ValorIr>
                                    <ValorCsll>0</ValorCsll>
                                    <IssRetido>2</IssRetido>
                                    <ValorIss>0</ValorIss>
                                    <ValorIssRetido>0</ValorIssRetido>
                                    <OutrasRetencoes>0</OutrasRetencoes>
                                    <BaseCalculo>1.00</BaseCalculo>
                                    <Aliquota>0</Aliquota>
                                    <ValorLiquidoNfse>1.00</ValorLiquidoNfse>
                                    <DescontoIncondicionado>0</DescontoIncondicionado>
                                    <DescontoCondicionado>0</DescontoCondicionado>
                                </Valores>
                                <ItemListaServico>701</ItemListaServico>
                                <CodigoCnae>0</CodigoCnae>
                                <Discriminacao>Auditoria Ambiental</Discriminacao>
                                <CodigoMunicipio>0000000</CodigoMunicipio>
                            </Servico>
                            <Prestador>
                                <Cnpj>00000000000000</Cnpj>
                                <InscricaoMunicipal/>
                            </Prestador>
                            <Tomador>
                                <IdentificacaoTomador>
                                    <CpfCnpj>
                                        <Cnpj>00000000000000</Cnpj>
                                    </CpfCnpj>
                                </IdentificacaoTomador>
                                <RazaoSocial>EMPRESA TESTE LTDA</RazaoSocial>
                                <Endereco>
                                    <Endereco>TESTE</Endereco>
                                    <Numero>00</Numero>
                                    <Complemento/>
                                    <Bairro>TESTE</Bairro>
                                    <CodigoMunicipio>0000000</CodigoMunicipio>
                                    <Uf>PR</Uf>
                                    <Cep>00000000</Cep>
                                </Endereco>
                                <Contato>
                                    <Telefone>11111111111</Telefone>
                                    <Email>email@email.com.br</Email>
                                </Contato>
                            </Tomador>
                        </InfRps>
                    </Rps>
                </ListaRps>
            </LoteRps>
            <Signature Id="NfsSignature">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11"/>
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                    <Reference URI="http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xhtml1-20000126/">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11"/></Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                        <DigestValue>Y2ZhNTExODY1OGRlOGU0MDI5NzU5MzZhMTVlMDVlYThhZTc5ZjcwYTA4NzQxYjIxMjQ0NTY3ZWE4YWVlNTIyOQ==</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>gJqmDLOaY4YdNEELf2c+hkrxcbz3x2og69YgiqtGR9zt0B+CzRodYoXB5euTB014sgHoCJejaBKwBaBq6BuLBmxUm02F4Lt8ApxQQF+e7561AcAV00YVb6nfILz4dzX32H8CjTYqK0cKONjYzAdNJinCpxybMEeS/6nkKS7vRmXgN18g7t1HUHvgWpirlYJ7mGeigFgYeUmd0JEmaycWyMtOzDhWq8KYeSFfP3Y/HlHQpMX6zh7tRw2oVlRCJQnRazedzLNY74gcZjd8fX5YrqERK6ExhhALJH8BGVg5uwhHC8llvO5EPnRSHTXkcqrBZihF/1LKbTvqQgjTCIiQPQ==</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <X509Data>
                        <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
                    </X509Data>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
        </EnviarLoteRpsEnvio>
    </RecepcionarLoteRps>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Link do WS com as especificações:** https://isscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br/Iss.NfseWebService/nfsews.asmx?op=RecepcionarLoteRps

Alguma dica para resolver esse problema?

Comment: Olá caro BigBoss, 403 provavelmente não tem haver com certificados de segurança, o problema deve ser na autenticação na camada da aplicação. Verifique se os dados de autenticação passados no seu xml estão correto.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento adicionei o XML enviado. Então não há nada de errado com as configurações acima?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acredito que estas sejam todas as tags exigidas pelo WS. A autenticação não seria as tags de assinatura?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu remove as tagas de SOAP padrões e adicionei o atributo xmlsn que estava faltando. (todas as outras tags já estavam no primeiro exemplo)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento agradeço pela ajuda, realmente não entendo tanto de SOAP. Acrescentei as tagas de SOAP inclusas no XML real (envelope e body), também acrescentei o link para as especificações exigidas pelo WS.

Comment: BigBoss acho que encontrei o problema, formulei uma resposta, pq não ia ter como só comentar. Espero que seja isto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Atualizando a resposta correta para o problema:**

Na verdade o endpoint deve ser sim HTTPS, o endpoint com HTTP existe mas não funciona para transmitir os arquivos RPS (NFS-e), estranhamente ele pode ser usado para validar o XML enviado, por isso obteve aquela resposta de erro na tag  conforme a resposta do Guilherme.
também utilizando o endpoint em HTTP não é possível enviar o certificado, que é necessário para a autenticação no WS.

E o problema com o erro 403 (acesso proibido) é na verdade com o certificado enviado. O Certificado deve ser **exatamente** o mesmo importado no sistema ISS (WS de Curitiba). Não pode ser o certificado original (.pfx, p12 e etc), deve ser o mesmo arquivo exportado pelo Internet Explorer (com a chave privada e todas as extensões).

Melhor explicado nesta outra pergunta: [curitiba ws problema no envio do certificado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/327011/curitiba-ws-problema-no-envio-do-certificado/373535#373535)

No **$headers**, não é necessário enviar o "host" como pârametro.

```
$headers = [
    'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($xml),
    'SOAPAction: http://www.e-governeapps2.com.br/RecepcionarLoteRps'
];
```

Também explicando o erro da tag  (retornado pela validação do XML no endpoint HTTP), o formato esperado de data e hora pelo WS é **"yyyy-mm-ddThh:ii:ss"**, exemplo: "2019-04-01T10:00:00".

Para quem estiver com interesse ou esteja com o mesmo problema, existe esta API em desenvolvimento que está funcionando para enviar o RPS para o WS de Curitiba: [sped-nfe-egoverne](https://github.com/nfephp-org/sped-nfse-egoverne/tree/master/examples)

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho certeza, mas creio que isto esteja errado:

```
$headers = [
    'POST /Iss.NfseWebService/nfsews.asmx HTTP/1.1', <---- ISTO
```

Não tem porque enviar o "VERBO" nos headers, o proprio curl já gera o "verbo", esse caminho `/Iss.NfseWebService/nfsews.asmx` deveria ser parte do "endpoint" (da URL), deve ser algo assim:

```
$headers = [
    'Host: isscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br',
    'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($xml),
    'SOAPAction: http://www.e-governeapps2.com.br/RecepcionarLoteRps'
];

$endpoint = 'https://isscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br/Iss.NfseWebService/nfsews.asmx';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, "{$path}_cert.pem");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, "{$path}_priKEY.pem");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD, '******'); // senha do certificado

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Coloquei no endpoint o `https://isscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br/`, não tenho certeza se este é o domínio, só deduzi pelo `host:`.

Não encontrei na documentação que afirme que HTTPS é exigido, sem usar HTTPS consegui obter o resultado fazendo isto:

```
$headers = [
    'Host: isscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br',
    'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($xml),
    'SOAPAction: http://www.e-governeapps2.com.br/RecepcionarLoteRps'
];

$endpoint = 'http://isscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br/Iss.NfseWebService/nfsews.asmx';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$resposta = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

echo "Resposta HTTP: $status<br>\n",
     "Resposta do SOAP: ", htmlespecialchars($resposta);
```

Eu obtive isto:

```
Resposta HTTP: 500
Resposta do SOAP: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Server was unable to read request. ---&gt; There is an error in XML document (19, 72). ---&gt; The string '2018-08-30 04:11:00T00:00:00' is not a valid AllXsd value.</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Sendo o erro:

> There is an error in XML document (19, 72). ---> The string '2018-08-30 04:11:00T00:00:00' is not a valid AllXsd value.

Ou seja o problema esta nesta linha do seu XML:

```
<DataEmissao>2018-08-30 04:11:00T00:00:00</DataEmissao>
```

Comment: tentei estas alterações e não funcionou, continua retornando 403. Vou tentar entrar em contato com o suporte da prefeitura e torcer para que respondam, já que não é possível encontrar documentação mais recente do que de 2013 :/

Comment: @BigBoss tenta enviar sem https, assim `'http://isscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br/Iss.NfseWebService/nfsews.asmx';` e remove as linhas que contem `CURLOPT_SSLCERT`, `CURLOPT_SSLKEY` e `CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD`

Comment: @BigBoss testei aqui e parece que funcionou trocando HTTPS por HTTP, não achei na documentação se HTTPS é obrigatório ou não, ainda sim consegui obter a seguinte mensagem de erro `Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in XML document (19, 72). ---> The string '2018-08-30 04:11:00T00:00:00' is not a valid AllXsd value`, editei a resposta.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda. Funcionou trocando o HTTPS por HTTP, e mantendo o POST no headers (não sei realmente se faz alguma diferença). Agora estou com outro problema com o certificado, mas isso já é outra coisa rs

Comment: Se puder editar a sua resposta e acrescentar a parte do HTTP pode ser que ajude alguém com a mesma dúvida no futuro :)