# Curitiba WS - problema no envio do certificado

Tags: php, libcurl, openssl

Estou tentando realizar a comunicação com o WS de Curitiba (ISS Curitiba) para o envio e consulta de lotes RPS (lotes de NFS-e), porém o WS sempre me retornar o erro:

**"E504 - Error: O certificado digital do prestador de serviços é obrigatório".**

Então a minha dúvida é, que arquivos eu devo enviar? O certificado do cliente (.pem ou .pfx?), a chave pública? a chave privada? Alguém que já teve esse trabalho poderia me ajudar?

Não encontrei muita coisa nos manuais e ainda não consegui contato com o suporte da prefeitura.

Estou utilizando a biblioteca curl (conforme o código abaixo):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $path.'_cert.pem'); // certificado do cliente
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $path.'_priKEY.pem'); // chave privada
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, 'PEM');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD, '******'); // senha do certificado

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

**Outros detalhes técnicos:**

Headers:

```
$headers = [
   'POST /Iss.NfseWebService/nfsews.asmx HTTP/1.1',
   'HOST: '.$url,
   'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
   'Content-Length: '.strlen($xml),
   'SOAPAction: http://www.e-governeapps2.com.br/RecepcionarLoteRps'
];
```

Criação do certificado do cliente:

```
// recebe o certificado pfx
openssl_pkcs12_read(file_get_contents('certificado.pfx'), $out, '******'));
// grava chave privada e o cartificado (sem a chave privada)
openssl_pkey_export_to_file($out['pkey'], $path.'_priKEY.pem');
openssl_x509_export_to_file($out['cert'], $path.'_cert.pem');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para alguém que ainda esteja com este erro, depois de tanto tempo consegui fazer funcionar a comunicação com o WS de Curitiba (ISS).

Primeiro, o certificado usado deve ser exatamente o mesmo arquivo importado na plataforma do ISS Curitiba, não pode ser o arquivo .pfx original e sim o gerado pelo Internet Explorer. Quando for exportar o certificado, deve incluir a chave privada e também todas as extensões.

Na sua aplicação é necessário obter os dados do certificado exportado com a função:

```
openssl_pkcs12_read();
```

Após isso, precisa salvar os arquivos extraídos (certificado/chave pública e chave privada) em arquivos temporários .pem que serão usados para enviar e realizar a autenticação no WS.

Para gravar a chave privada é necessário realizar uma encriptação do arquivo:

```
openssl_pkey_export(
   $certificate->privateKey,
   $privateKeyPath,
   $password
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $path.'_cert.pem'); // certificado exportado/chave publica
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $path.'_priKEY.pem'); // chave privada
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD, $password); // senha da chave privada exportada
```

As outras configurações do CURL pode continuar iguais.

Para quem tenha interesse e não queira ter todo esse trabalho manual, também existe essa API em desenvolvimento que realiza essa comunicação: [sped-nfse-egoverne](https://github.com/nfephp-org/sped-nfse-egoverne/tree/master/examples)

Ainda não está totalmente completa mas funciona perfeitamente. Só é preciso ter atenção com a confusão dos certificados (o original e o exportado).